# What is the best approach for handling icon size for different screens like large and normal

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, screen-size

Say you design for a normal screen(4 inch) of hdpi density, but then when you see it on a large screen(7 inch) of hdpi density the icons are too small. 
Initially what I did was have to create a folder drawable-large-hdpi, then take the icons from xhdpi and copy it in there.
 It seemed to work well, but then when I came across a large xhdpi screen it caused problems because Android was looking in the drawable-large-hdpi first before looking in drawable-xhdpi folder, because large has precedence. Creating another folder drawable-large-xhdpi and copying files seems inefficient as you have to do this for the ever expanding dpi screens.

So rather than having "wrap_content" on your icons inside the app should you be setting a particular width/height e.g. layout_width/height=@dimen/icon_size, then in the dimensions.xml set different widths in the values and values-large folder?

It would be nice if one could set it as a percentage of the parent view, but layout-weight only works for certain scenarios of linear-layouts

Are there better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ScreenPercentImageView extends ImageView {

    private float mWidthPercent = 100;
    private double mDrawableScalePercent;

    public ScreenPercentImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScreenPercentImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setup(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScreenPercentImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.ScreenPercentImageView, 0, 0);
        try {
            mWidthPercent = a.getFloat(
                    R.styleable.ScreenPercentImageView_widthPercentIV, 50);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int parentWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int parentHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        int width;

        if (parentHeight > parentWidth)
            width = (int) (parentWidth * mWidthPercent / 100);
        else
            width = (int) (parentHeight * mWidthPercent / 100);

        mDrawableScalePercent = (double) width / parentWidth;
        int height = getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() * width
                / getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

    }

    public double getDrawableScalePercent() {
        return mDrawableScalePercent;
    }

}
```

This is an ImageView that you can use as an example. I created it so it can use the width as a percentage of the screen size. It will scale the height appropriately. You can use this concept to have it use the width of the parent instead of the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Your layouts used on bigger screens, should no be just "stretched-out"/enlarged versions of the smaller screen ones. Android is great at loading and creating different layouts, according to how much free space you have on your screen.

Fragments were introduced to Android, so that you can do all kinds of stuff, in order to utilize the different screen sizes to the fullest.

Use the smallest width availabe bucket (layout-swXdp where X is the number of dp you like) and create unique layouts when the screen has enough space inside, and your tablet users will love you

More info here: [Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)